# Working with arrays in a service

Tags: jquery, arrays, service, enumerable

I have a `navigation` service that has a few properties that I will need to use to display the navigation properly. I am implementing a priority style navigation [Priority-Nav](http://gijsroge.github.io/priority-nav.js/) which will show only items that fit on screen in a menu bar at the bottom of the view and place the remaining in an offscreen style navigation.

Each route defines it's own nav items that should be present on that page so that when navigating pages the items can all be unique to that particular view.

So as an example and route can define it's nav items like so...

```
navigationService: Ember.inject.service('navigation'),
activate() {
    this.get('navigationService').set('navigationMenuItems', ['nav-buttons/user-button',...]);
},
```

This should be the nav items that should be available to the page. Then there should be sub array of those items that include only the items that will fit in the navigation, and the rest should be in an array representing the ones that don't and should render into an off screen navigation.

On my service I have defined these like so...

```
navigationMenuItems: [],
visibleNavItems: [],
hiddenNavItems: [],
```

There is an `on.('init')` function that sets up an `on resize` event listener to update another property with the total width of the window so that calculations can be done.

I defined an observer to watch for changes in either the width of the window or items being added to the overall `nav-items` that should be available to the page

```
recalculateNavItems: Ember.observer('windowWidth','navigationMenuItems.[]',function(){
var self = this;
    var numItems = self.get('navigationMenuItems').length;
    var itemsWidth = numItems * 60;
    var availableSpace = self.get('windowWidth') - 60;
    if(itemsWidth > availableSpace){
        self.get('hiddenNavItems').push(self.get('navigationMenuItems').pop());
    }
})
```

Here I am getting the amount of menu items total, the width of all of those combined, and then the width of the container that will show the visible ones. Then I determine if there are too many items for the container, and I'm attempting to pull one off the end and push it into the hidden nav items which will show in the off screen navigation.

1. I need to understand how to make these arrays in ember so that the templates can display them and I can still observe them the way I need to
   I may be able to figure this next one out myself but
2. When the user loads the app I need to figure out how many items I need to pop off the end and add to the hidden menu items, not just assume one will do it
3. Am I going at this all wrong?

I can maybe explain this better if necessary in the slack or somewhere else I needed? I feel like I'm right about there but just need the extra nudge to get me in the right direction.